# How to update SimpleAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

Is it possible to update a SimpleAdapter?  I have a list of data and a footer that says "See Next Results" When that list item is clicked I capture the event and get new data.  I then want to replace the data in the ListView with this new data but I can't figure out how to do it.  Any Ideas?  I don't want to use an ArrayAdapter, cause as far as I can see the items can only hold one string where I need it to hold multiple strings and ints.

Answer (score 11):

*Update*: According to del116, you can indeed give `SimpleAdapter` a mutable map and then manually call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged` method when you need the list to update.  However, my point below stands about the documentation of SimpleAdapter specifying that it is for static data; using it for mutable data is going counter to its design, so if you use this technique I would be sure to check on whether it continues to work in new Android releases as they emerge.

(Original commentary follows:)

If you look at the [SimpleAdapter description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) it says it is "An easy adapter to map *static data* to views defined in an XML file."  I've added the emphasis -- put simply, `SimpleAdapater` isn't built for use with data that changes; it handles static data only.  If you can't use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) because your data has more than a single bit of text, then you will either have to build your own custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html), or put your data in a DB and use one of the [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)s.

As a last resort, if you don't need much performance, you *could* update a `ListView` backed by a `SimpleAdapter` by building a whole new `SimpleAdapter` instance any time your data changes and telling the list view to use it via `setListAdapter`.

Comment: Your answer here is really misleading.  After updating the array data and calling notifyDataSetChanged() on my SimpleAdapter, I was able to update the simpleAdapter.  No need to use ArrayAdapter to call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @dell116 Fair enough.  I referred to that possibility in the end of my answer, but I've promoted it to the top based on your feedback that it does in fact work; I had not tested it.  I still maintain that doing such a thing merits some caution since the SimpleAdapter documentation specifically states that it is for static data.

Comment: Looking back at this now...wow.  I knew nothing about programming or the intended purpose of SimpleAdapter.  If you're using a ListView (or any AdapterView) backed by a data structure that will change don't use SimpleAdapter.  Foot.inMouth(true);

Answer (score 3):

```
ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.loglist);
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
String[] from = { "time", "message" };
int[] to = { R.id.logtime, R.id.logmessage };

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list,R.layout.log_list_row, from,to);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Call this function each time to update the ListView. Keep in Mind that You have to update the *list* variable with new Data..

Hope this Helps..:)

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleAdapter` is meant for static data, so your performance may vary. The best solution is probably to switch to a different type of adapter, such as `ArrayAdapter`, or make a new `SimpleAdapter` every time you change the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get notifyDataSetChanged() to work on updating my SimpleAdapter, so instead I tried first removing all views that were attached to the parent layout using removeAllViews(), then adding the ListView, and that worked, allowing me to update the UI:

```
LinearLayout results = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.results);
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( this, list, R.layout.directory_row, 
                    new String[] { "name", "dept" }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.dept } );

for (...) { 
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("dept", dept);
    list.add(map);
}

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
results.removeAllViews();     
results.addView(lv);
```