# Images in ListView over SimpleAdapter are not updatet after change

Tags: android

I have a list-activity using a row-based layout for elements of the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:id="@+id/exerciseText" android:textSize="40sp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/solutionImage" android:scaleType="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I fill the list with a SimpleAdapter and provide the data over this List:

```
List<HashMap<String, String> > data;
```

I initially load the data with some strings and default image. The main images are loaded later. The images are saved as resource ids

```
Integer.toString(R.drawable.check)
```

Now the problem: 
While the images I initially put into the list are loading properly, updated items don't change their appearance directly. They have to be out of the viewable area(In the scrolled view I have to scroll until they are out of the window. If I scroll them back they changed their appearance). This problem does not only concern to images but also on texts(which I don't update in my App).

Do I have to use an ArrayAdapter rather than a SimpleAdapter to get automatically updating work?

Thanks for tips in any kind and please ask if I didn't make myself clear

Answer (score 1):

A [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) is

*An easy adapter to map **static data** to views*

thus if your data is subjected to changes in the future, you should use an ArrayAdapter. In the latter, after updating the data call

```
mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and the images should update automatically

PS. [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313347/how-to-update-simpleadapter-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleAdapter` also supports the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so no need to use a `ArrayAdapter`