# Difference between ContentObserver and DatasetObserver?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, contentobserver

What is difference between `ContentObserver` and `DatasetObserver`?

When one or another should be used?

I get `Cursor` with single row. I want to be notified about data changes - eg. when row is updated.

Which observer class should I register?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using a `ContentProvider` (via `ContentResolver` or `Activity.managedQuery()`) to get your data, simply attach a `ContentObserver` to your `Cursor`.  The code in `onChange()` will be called whenever the `ContentResolver` broadcasts a notification for the `Uri` associated with your cursor.

```
Cursor myCursor = managedQuery(myUri, projection, where, whereArgs, sortBy);
myCursor.registerContentObserver(new ContentObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        // This cursor's Uri has been notified of a change
        // Call cursor.requery() or run managedQuery() again
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Make sure your `ContentProvider` is a "good citizen" and registers the `Uri` with the cursor after a query:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

It should also notify the `ContentResolver` of any changes to the underlying data (for instance, during insert, delete, and update operations on your SQLite database):

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

This approach is a good example of the Observer Pattern of object-oriented design.

Comment: Ok, and in which way `DatasetObserver` differs from `ContentProvider`?

Comment: I haven't used a `DataSetObserver`, but it seems from the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) a `DataSetObserver` is notified of cursor lifecycle changes such as closing and requerying, whereas `ContentObserver` is used to watch for changes in underlying data.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Now I see. `DatasetObserver` observes `Cursor` state, whereas `ContentProvider` observes underlying content changes. Thanks!

Comment: `requery()` is now deprecated, has the method for doing this changed?

Comment: Using managedQuery is also deprecated.  The currently recommended approach is to asynchronously query your ContentProvider with CursorLoaders.  They observe changes and automatically requery their cursors.  See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182920/what-are-the-benefits-of-cursorloaders

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this question is still on anyone's radar.  I have been struggling with the same question for a little while now.  What I came up with as my litmus test for deciding whether to use a DataSet Observer or a ContentObserver is pretty straight-forward:

If I need to send a URI in my notification I use a ContentObserver.   If I simply need to notify one object that another object has changed -- I use a DataSetObserver.

The delimiting factor, for me at least, is does the object that is sending out the notification expose it's underlying resources (be they objects, records, queries, or cursors) as "Universal Resource Identifiers" to the rest of the application;  or does the object hide the source of its data.

Answer (score 2):

To provide the supplement to ptc's answer, `DataSetObserver` is used for handling content changes in the [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), for example, it can be used for [updating listview dynamically with Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320358/update-listview-dynamically-with-adapter). You can register a `DataSetObserver` using the `Adapter#registerDataSetObserver()` method.

`DataSetObserver` can also be used to observe the content changes in the [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

From my last app developed I can say.
The main difference between ContentObserver and DataSetObserver, is that ContentObserver makes to  Observer any change affects on ContentProvider.  On the other hand, DataSetObserver Observer any change effect on the database.

Comment: DatasetObserver can be registered with a BaseAdapter - which isn't constrained solely to a database.