# What are the benefits of CursorLoaders?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-cursor, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I use `Cursors` extensively in my app, to load and occasionally write information from and to a database. I have seen that Honeycomb and the Compatibility Package have new `Loader` classes designed to help with loading data in a "good" way.

Essentially, are these new classes (in particular `CursorLoader`) considerably better than previous methods of managing data? What is the benefit of a `CursorLoader` over managed `Cursors` for example?

And I use a `ContentProvider` to deal with data, which obviously takes `Uris` but how does this mesh with the `initLoader()` method? Must I set up each of my `Fragments` to use Loaders individually? And how unique does the id need to be for each loader, is it over the scope of my app or just a fragment? Is there any simple way of simply passing a `Uri` to a CursorLoader to query my data?

All I can see at the moment is that Loaders add an unnecessary extra step to getting my data into my app, so can someone explain them to me better?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are two key benefits to using a `CursorLoader` in your app over `Activity.managedQuery()`:

1. The query is handled on a background thread for you (courtesy of being build on `AsyncTaskLoader`) so large data queries do not block the UI.  This is something the docs recommended you do for yourself when using a plain `Cursor`, but now it's done under the hood.
2. `CursorLoader` is auto-updating.  In addition to performing the initial query, the `CursorLoader` registers a `ContentObserver` with the dataset you requested and calls `forceLoad()` on itself when the data set changes.  This results in you getting async callbacks anytime the data changes in order to update the view.

Each `Loader` instance is also handled through the singular `LoaderManager`, so you still don't have to manage the cursor directly, and now the connection can persist even beyond a single `Activity`.  `LoaderManager.initLoader()` and `LoaderManager.restartLoader()` allow you to reconnect with an existing `Loader` already set up for your query and, in some cases, instantly get the latest data if it is available.

Your `Activity` or `Fragment` will likely now implement the `LoaderManager.Callback` interface.  Calling `initLoader()` will result in the `onCreateLoader()` method where you will construct the query and a new `CursorLoader` instance, if necessary.  The `onLoadFinished()` method will be fired each time new data is available, and will include the latest `Cursor` for you to attach to the view or otherwise iterate through.

In addition, there is a pretty good example of all this fitting together on the `LoaderManager` class documentation page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

Comment: Cool, thanks for that explaination! Just a couple of questions: is the id supplied to `initLoader()` mean to be unique or each set of data you need to query? And because I have multiple activities which each use different tables of my database, is there any way I can create a class which handles each `CursorLoader`, much like a `ContentProvider` can handle multiple `Cursors` with `query`?

Comment: The id value identifies a unique `Loader` instance with the manager, you can get access to the same one again if you ask `LoaderManager` sometime after it's already been created.  Since each `CursorLoader` is basically created to execute a specific query, you could say that an id maps to a data set.  Although there are methods on `CursorLoader` to dynamically change the query parameters as well, so that's not required to be the case.

Comment: `LoaderManager` is really the single class that handles each `Loader` for you, but if you mean can you create a single class to manage `LoaderManager.Callback` for multiple `Loader` instances, the answer is yes.  Multiple callbacks can be attached for a single `Loader` id value, and multiple ids could point back to the same callback implementation.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone finds themselves in a similar situation, here's what I've done:

- Created a class which implements `LoaderCallbacks` and handles *all* the queries you'll need.
- Supply this with a `Context` and the `Adapter` in question.
- Create unique IDs for each query you'll use (if you use a `UriMatcher`, might as well use the same ones)
- Make a convenience method which transfers queries into the bundle required for the `LoaderCallbacks`
- That's pretty much it :) I put some of my code below to show exactly what I did

In my `GlobalCallbacks` class:

```
public static final String PROJECTION = "projection";
public static final String SELECTION = "select";
public static final String SELECTARGS = "sargs";
public static final String SORT = "sort";

Context mContext;
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

public GlobalCallbacks(Context context, SimpleCursorAdapter adapter) {
    mContext = context;
    mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Uri contentUri = AbsProvider.customIntMatch(id);
    if (contentUri != null) {
        return new CursorLoader(mContext, contentUri, args.getStringArray(PROJECTION), args.getString(SELECTION), 
                args.getStringArray(SELECTARGS), args.getString(SORT));
    } else return null;

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);      
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

And when I wanted to use a `CursorLoader` (`Helper.bundleArgs()` is the convenience bundling method):

```
scAdapt = new Adapters.NewIndexedAdapter(mHost, getMenuType(), 
                null, new String[] { "name" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(
                GlobalCallbacks.GROUP,
                Helper.bundleArgs(new String[] { "_id", "name" }),
                new GlobalCallbacks(mHost, scAdapt));
        setListAdapter(scAdapt);
```

And in Helper:

```
public static Bundle bundleArgs(String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray(GlobalCallbacks.PROJECTION, projection);
    b.putString(GlobalCallbacks.SELECTION, selection);
    b.putStringArray(GlobalCallbacks.SELECTARGS, selectionArgs);
    return b;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

**EDIT**

To explain more thoroughly:

- First, an adapter with a null `Cursor` is initialised. We don't supply it with a `Cursor` because `GlobalCallbacks` will give the adapter the correct `Cursor` in `onLoadFinished(..)`
- Next, we tell `LoaderManager` we want to initialise a new `CursorLoader`. We supply a new `GlobalCallbacks` instance (which implements `Loader.Callbacks`) which will then monitor the loading of the cursor. We have to supply it with the adapter too, so it can swap in the new `Cursor` once its done loading. At some point, the `LoaderManager` (which is built into the OS) will call `onCreateLoader(..)` of `GlobalCallbacks` and start asynchronously loading data
- `Helper.bundleArgs(..)` just puts arguments for the query into a `Bundle` (e.g. columns projection, sort order, WHERE clause)
- Then we set the `Fragment`'s `ListAdapter`. The cursor will still be null at this point, so it will show a loading sign or empty message until `onLoadFinished()` is called

Comment: Hey, I have a quick question. First though, I want to thank you for providing this. You really helped me understand what I needed to do and where to look. So my question is about your convenience method. I'm not really sure how it works. Could you explain that last bit of code if you have time please. Thanks again!

Comment: See my updated answer, let me know if you need anything further

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I see. I finally got it!! I kind of understand. But How is that `Bundle` sent into `onCreateLoader`? The tutorial I saw does it right in onCreateLoader, never really using it. I was under the assumption that I didn't need to use it.

Comment: I think the Bundle is more useful if you want to dynamically change your query. For example if you had a list of items and you wanted all of them, you wouldn't need the Bundle, but it could come in handy if you want to then filter them, as you wouldn't need two different CursorLoaders (you'd just check if there was a filter query in the Bundle).

Comment: Ahh, I really appreciate your time. One more thing, could you rewrite that convenience method exactly how you have it, and which class its in? But besides that, i'm all set. You have helped me out immensely. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have it any more (I was having issues with ProGuard and this class so I got rid of it), but I'll rewrite it above

Comment: Oh, ok. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No probs, I've rewritten the base bundleArgs() above, you can just make the others passing null arguments.