# How can I use a cursorLoader in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

```
I have a `cursorLoader` which is working fine.
```

The problem is I'm not using it like I'm supposed to, I load the data from the `cursorLoader` into `arrayLists` and then use the lists.

I found this tutorial which shows how to use a `cursorLoader` with a `viewPager` but I don't understand how to actually make it happen.

> http://tumble.mlcastle.net/post/25875136857/bridging-cursorloaders-and-viewpagers-on-android

I have a fragment which looks like this:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;
    // Store instance variables
    private String email,about,imagepath,latitude,longitude;
    Button getDirections;

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String email,String about,String imagepath, String latitude, String longitude) {
        FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("email", email);
        args.putString("about", about);
        args.putString("imagepath", imagepath);
        args.putString("latitude", latitude);
        args.putString("longitude", longitude);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        email = getArguments().getString("email");
        about = getArguments().getString("about");
        imagepath = getArguments().getString("imagepath");
        latitude = getArguments().getString("latitude");
        longitude = getArguments().getString("longitude");
    }

    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zzfragment_pager_items, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listpager_imageView);
        TextView about = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listpager_text);
        TextView emaill = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listpager_title);
        about.setText(this.about);
        emaill.setText(this.email);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();
        imageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imagepath, imageView, options);

        getDirections = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getdirections);

        getDirections.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitude + "," + longitude + " (" + email + ")";
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));

                mapIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

                getActivity().startActivity(mapIntent);

            }
        });

//        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtopager, container, false);
        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

And I was calling it in this class:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends FragmentActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    ArrayList<String> e

mail = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> about = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> imagepath = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> latitude = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> longitude = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager_fragment);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
}

private SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

// Extend from SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter now instead for more dynamic ViewPager items
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<String> email;
    private final ArrayList<String> about;
    private final ArrayList<String> imagepath;
    private final ArrayList<String> latitude;
    private final ArrayList<String> longitude;
    private int listPosition;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,ArrayList<String> email,ArrayList<String> about, ArrayList<String> imagepath,ArrayList<String> latitude,ArrayList<String> longitude,int lPosition) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.imagepath=imagepath;
        this.email=email;
        this.about = about;
        this.latitude= latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        listPosition = lPosition;
    }

// Returns total number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return email.size();
}



 // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
//            return FirstFragment.newInstance(listPosition+position, email.get(listPosition+position));
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(email.get(position), about.get(position),imagepath.get(position),latitude.get(position),longitude.get(position));
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection =
            {
                    ActivitiesTable.KEY_EMAIL,
                    ActivitiesTable.KEY_ABOUT,
                    ActivitiesTable.KEY_IMAGEPATH,
                    ActivitiesTable.KEY_LATITUDE,
                    ActivitiesTable.KEY_LONGITUTDE

            };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, NameContentProvider.NAME_ACTIVITIES_URI, projection,
            null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            email.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("email")));
            about.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("about")));
            imagepath.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("imagepath")));
            latitude.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("serverLatitude")));
            longitude.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("serverLongitude")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    int listPosition = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");


    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),email,about,imagepath,latitude,longitude,listPosition);
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(listPosition);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {



   }
}
```

How can I modify the code to use the viewPager with the loader directly by using that tutorial, instead of storing everything in lists and then using the lists ?

Comment: First of all, instead of dealing with 5 different ArrayLists, why dont You simply create a class that represents all 5 values and put those objects into a single ArrayList? That approach would make Your code much cleaner and as for me, the outcome is just fine then

Comment: I don't want to use the lists anymore. I already found a way of using the data directly from the cursorLoader but it uses some deprecated methods. This one looks better but I have no idea how to make it work

Comment: The method that I'm using which loads data directly from the loader without the arraylists extends `pagerAdapter` and uses `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem` which are deprecated. I like the method that I posted here more but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Cast the view argument within instantiateItem and destroyItem to ViewGroup - View-parametered method is deprecated and according to docs you should use the ViewGroup variation

Comment: Did that. Thank you. I have a lot of views which will be displayed. The best thing to use is `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of the simple PagerAdapter ?

Comment: **Can you please refer one:** 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760647/viewpager-pageradapter-with-cursor-cursorloader-onloadfinished-doesnt-get-call

Comment: @hitesh141 I have already implemented that and it's working.. but I thought that this method is better

Comment: @ Bogdan Daniel: yes, i prefer this because of some efficiency concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I'm writing an answer..

You have an activity that implements `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. Your activity receives `onLoadFinished` callback when your data is loaded. Inside this method you have a `Cursor` that should be displayed in your `ViewPager`.

To display the data from `Cursor`, you call `swapCursor` method on the adapter. So, do not create adapter each time you load data. Create it once, and then just call `swapCursor` on it.

Also, do not find `ViewPager` each time - `findViewById` is a heavy operation, it should be performed once the view hierarchy is created.

So, your `onLoadFinished` will look like this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (adapterViewPager == null) {
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), cursor);
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    } else {
        adapterViewPager.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first I would do, if I were in you is to create a model class, which will hold the information contained in your cursor.

```
public class Information implements Parcelable {

   public String imagepath;
   public String email;
   public String about;
   public String latitude;
   public String longitude;


protected Information(Parcel in) {
    imagepath = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    about = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readString();
    longitude = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(imagepath);
    dest.writeString(email);
    dest.writeString(about);
    dest.writeString(latitude);
    dest.writeString(longitude);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Information> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Information>() {
    @Override
    public Information createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Information(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Information[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Information[size];
    }
};
}
```

And that's already most of it. The second thing that I would do, is to create two helper methods, one to create an instance of this class, reading the data from the Cursor, and another to create a collection.

```
 public static Information createInfoFromCursor(Cursor c) {
         Information info = new Information();
         info.email = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("email")));
         info.about = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("about")));
         info.imagepath =(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("imagepath")));
         info.latitude = (cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("serverLatitude")));
         info.longitude = (cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("serverLongitude")));
         return info;
  }
```

and

```
 public static ArrayList<Information> createInfoListFromCursor(Cursor c) {
    ArrayList<Information> info = new ArrayList<>();
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        info.add(createInfoFromCursor());
    }
    return info;
 }
```

now you can decide to provide the `Cursor`, or the `ArrayList<Information>`, to the adapter. If you decide to pass the `Cursor`, In your adapter you will have

```
Cursor cursor;

 public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,Cursor c) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    cursor = c;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   cursor.moveAtPosition(position);
   Information info = createInfoFromCursor(cursor);
   // create a version of `newInstance` that takes an Information object
   return FirstFragment.newInstance(info);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return cursor == null ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
}      

public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (newCursor == cursor) {
        return null;
    }
    cursor = newCursor;
    if (newCursor != null) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
    return oldCursor;
}
```

in your Activity, create an instance of the Adapter,  passing a null cursor, and keep it as member classe. When `onLoadFinished` is called, use that reference to call `swapCursor`, to refresh the Adapter's dataset

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping 5 arrays of data just keep the cursor in the view pager adapter and load the data from cursor when is needed. This way the UI will not block if you have a lot of items in your cursor.

Also you can add a method for swapping the cursor and notify that data has changed and viewpager will be refreshed instead of recreating and attaching the adapter each time (exactly as in the link that you mention)

The MyPagerAdapter should look like this:

```
Cursor cursor;

// Returns total number of pages 
@Override 
public int getCount() { 
    return cursor==null?0:cursor.getCount();
} 

// Returns the fragment to display for that page 
@Override 
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // position the cursor first
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    // read each field
    String email = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("email"));
    ...
    return FirstFragment.newInstance(email, ...);
} 

public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    this.cursor = cursor;
    // notify that data has changed and viewpager needs to be refreshed
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Don't forget to clean once the loader is reset

```
@Override 
public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapterViewPager.swapCursor(null) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a good simple example of how to populate a ViewPager with Fragments from a Cursor, look at the code of [this Activity](https://github.com/cbeyls/fosdem-companion-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/be/digitalia/fosdem/activities/TrackScheduleEventActivity.java) I wrote for the FOSDEM Companion app.

Note: you should avoid putting a map inside a ViewPager because touch events will be intercepted by the MapView and the user will not be able to swipe to the next or previous page.