# Notify Activity in Android to refresh when data is updated

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a background Service which updates the database in an Android App.
In the App this data is displayed, but I am having trouble finding a good way to trigger a refresh of the data.

Initially I just refreshed each time a view resumed, but that doesn't work obviously if the data is updated while the view is shown.

On iOS I use notifications, which I register in the view, and is triggered by the update process when completed. Is there a way to do something similar in Android to trigger an update on the UI thread from a background thread?

Comment: you can use Broadcast receiver component of android to get to know your desired trigger

Comment: You can use a BroadCastReceiver with the custom intnet. Whenever that custom intent is  fired you can refresh the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BroadcastReciever in your Activity is the best way to update Activity from the Service.

Activity:

```
 BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

After that, all you need is to register some action for it in Activity:

```
 public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.action";

 IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
```

In your service you should build an intent and call sendBroadcast.

Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use a `BroadCastReceiver` if you update your database and you're using a `ContentProvider` to saving your data to the db then whenever data change on the `ContentProvider` it should notify that data has changed and in your on your activity you use a `CursorLoader` then the Loader is notified and UI updated, this is very easy to do and has the advantage that a `CursorLoader` will run the thread on background see more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183251/992063)

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I will need to look into that. That is a much more elegant solution then just to reload.