# how to let my SimpleCursorAdapter refresh automatically?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-adapter

i'm using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fill my list like this:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.fang_listlayout, 
            MainController.getInstance().getCursor(), 
            new String[] {"Foo", "Foo2"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.foo1, R.id.foo2}, 0);
```

now i want to implement, when something in the `Cursor` changed i want to refesh the list content automatically.

how to implement this?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430862/difference-between-contentobserver-and-datasetobserver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986071/1339473... whenver u enter into databse this update by adatper.requery() so..every time this is update databse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the managedQuery() and reQuery() methods. But these methods have been depricated.
Cause you have another way to manage, cursor and list view, by CursorLoader api, please see following link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html