# Android: How to create CursorAdapter from the data in an XML file

Tags: android, xml, listview, adapter, android-cursoradapter

In android can we create CursorAdapter from the data in an XML file? Here's the actual problem:

I need to create a ListView whose items can vary. Each items has three fields: ItemName, ItemValue, ItemUnit. If the adapter is created from an external file (eg: an XML file) provided to the application, then the number of items and it's field value can change without changing the application code. What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could just load the data from the xml file into a list of Maps and then use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html). That's probably the easiest thing to do. Note that you'll have to give the SimpleAdapter a mutable map and manually call notifyDataSetChanged whenever stuff changes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3408302/527288). If you're list isn't to big (less than 1000 items), you could probably get away with just creating a new adapter every time your data changes and then assign the new adapter to your list.